# Numbering quotations

Tags: numbering, environments, counters, quotation

I want to create a new environment `nquote` based on `displayquote` (form `csquotes` package) that I can number, and display that number on the side so I can cite quotations in my document, like you can do with equations.

This is what I have so far:

```
\usepackage[csquotes]
\newcounter{nquotes}
\newenvironment{nquote}
    {
    \refstepcounter{nquotes}
    (\thenquotes)\space
    \begin{displayquote}
    }
    { 
    \end{displayquote}
    }
```

but the number appears at the begining of the line before the quotation. I want it at the side of the quotation.

Comment: What package is providing `displayquote`? Or are you defining it yourself? In either case, add the necessary details, please.

Comment: @egreg: It's from the `csquotes` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I designed a solution with the help of @Ingmar who suggested to use `\marginpar`, but I used `\marginnote` (from `marginnote` package) instead:

```
\usepackage[csquotes]
\usepackage[marginnote]
\newcounter{nquotes}
\newenvironment{nquote}
    {
    \refstepcounter{nquotes}
    \begin{displayquote}
    \marginpar{(\thenquotes)}
    }
    { 
    \end{displayquote}
    }
```

Comment: \usepackage[marginnote] → \usepackage{marginnote} ? Shouldn't there be curly brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{nquotes}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{nquote}
 {%
  \refstepcounter{nquotes}%
  \renewcommand{\item}{\@item[\nquote@label]}%
  \begin{displayquote}%
 }
 {\end{displayquote}}
\newcommand{\nquote@label}{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\leftmargin][l]{\hspace{\labelsep}(\thenquotes)}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{displayquote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{displayquote}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{nquote}\label{x}
\lipsum[2]
\end{nquote}

The quote is number~\ref{x}.

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

A small modification to have the anchor at the right place if you're using `hyperref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{nquotes}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{nquote}
 {%
  \renewcommand{\item}{%
    \stepcounter{nquotes}%
    \@item[\nquote@label]%
    \addtocounter{nquotes}{-1}%
    \refstepcounter{nquotes}%
  }%
  \begin{displayquote}%
 }
 {\end{displayquote}}
\newcommand{\nquote@label}{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[\leftmargin][l]{\hspace{\labelsep}(\thenquotes)}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{displayquote}
\lipsum[2]
\end{displayquote}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{nquote}\label{x}
\lipsum[2]
\end{nquote}

The quote is number~\ref{x}.

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this very recently. Full example to follow:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{babel}

\newcounter{quote}
\AtBeginEnvironment{displayquote}{\refstepcounter{quote}}
\AtEndEnvironment{displayquote}{\hfill Quote \#\bfseries\thequote}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{displayquote} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod 
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
erat, sed diam voluptua.
\end{displayquote}

Some more text. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\begin{displayquote} Et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd  gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{displayquote}

Some more text. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea 
takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It is an interesting solution, but not exactly what I am looking for since I want the numbers displayed on the side of the page like with equations.

Comment: You can display the counter anywhere you like, multiple times, even. If you want it in the margin of your page, take a look at \marginpar` or packages with similar functionality.